# Variable Declaration Problems

Tags: java

I can't figure out why eclipse wants me to delete the ";" and replace it with with a ",".

```
numberOfTimes1 = numberOfTimes + numberOfDelayTimes;
```

I'm guessing it's some simple syntax thing that I forgot about. Could you please explain why it's doing that and also how to fix it. 
Entire Program

```
public class Spam {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //1- Taking an instance of Timer class.
        Timer timer = new Timer("Printer");

        //2- Taking an instance of class contains your repeated method.
        timeso t = new timeso();

        timer.schedule(t, 0, 10);
    }

}
class timeso extends TimerTask {
    //times member represent calling times.
    private int times = 0;
    int time = 6; //How long do you wish for the spamming to run?
    int numberOfTimes = time * 100;
    int delayTime = 5; //How long do you wish for the program to wait before spamming?
    int numberOfDelayTimes = delayTime * 100;
    numberOfTimes = numberOfTimes + numberOfDelayTimes;
    String spam;
    Random randomGenerator = new Random();

    public void run() {
        times++;
        if (times >= numberOfDelayTimes && times <= numberOfTimes+numberOfDelayTimes) {

            try {
                Robot typer = new Robot();
                //for(int x = 1;x <=randomGenerator.nextInt(5); x++){
                //  spam = spam + randomGenerator.nextInt(10);
                //}
                byte[] bytes = "spam".getBytes();
                //byte[] bytes = spam.getBytes();
                for (byte b : bytes){
                    int code = b;
                    // key code only handles [A-Z] (which is ASCII decimal [65-90])
                    if (code > 96 && code < 123) code = code - 32;
                    typer.delay(10/bytes.length+1);
                    typer.keyPress(code);
                    typer.keyRelease(code);
                }
                if(times % (randomGenerator.nextInt(25)+1) == 0){
                    typer.delay(10/bytes.length+1);
                    typer.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
                    typer.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
                }
            } 
            catch (AWTException e){
            } 
        } else {
            if (times >= numberOfTimes){
                try{
                    Robot typer = new Robot();
                    typer.delay(10);
                    typer.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
                    typer.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
                } catch(Exception e){

                }
                //Stop Timer.
                this.cancel();
            }
        }
}   
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to call a line of code outside of a method or constructor, and this is why the Java compiler (not Eclipse) is complaining. Do that sort of code in the constructor or method, not naked in the class.  In fact all that code in your timeso class is incorrect and needs to be in a method or constructor.

Note: you'll want to learn Java naming convention and stick with it, including starting class names with an upper-case letter and method and variable names with a lower-case letter. Doing this will help others (us!) understand your code better.

Comment: I can't put the  declaration code into run because it'd keep numberOfTimes at 1. Where would I put the code?

Comment: @Cammy_the_block: in the constructor that you've yet to but need to create.

Comment: If I have those declarations in the constructor how would run() access this?

Comment: @Cammy_the_block: not the **Declarations** -- they go in the class like you have them. But the compiler isn't complaining about them, is it. It's complaining about the non-declaration code that you're trying to run naked in the class.